# IndexError: index 20 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 20

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am working radio frequencies interference (RFI), I am trying to simulate the RFIs and them to the frequency range as per their classifications i.e., `[continuous, intermittent, malfunction]`. For the continuous RFIs, they will have to be everywhere. I did the calculations and got the values but I keep getting an error thus I can't plot the values I get.

This is what I have done;

```
def calculate_RFI(classifications, descriptions, amplitude, freq_samples=64, min_freq=1, max_freq=2, min_HA=-1.5, max_HA=1.5,sampling_H=60*3*2):
    '''
    This function calculates the RFI dataframe
    Parameters
    ----------
    classifications: list
        The list of classifications
    freq_samples: int
        The number of frequency samples
    min_freq: float
        The minimum frequency in GHz
    max_freq: float
        The maximum frequency in GHz
    min_HA: float
        The minimum hour angle in hours
    max_HA: float
        The maximum hour angle in hours
    sampling_H: float
        The sampling interval of the hour angle in hours
    '''
     # create a multidimensional meshgrid of the frequency and hour angle
    meshgrid = np.mgrid[min_freq:max_freq:freq_samples*1j,
                        min_HA:max_HA:sampling_H*1j]
    
    freq = meshgrid[0]
    HA = meshgrid[1]

    # create frequency and hour angle point size
    freq_point_size = (max_freq-min_freq)/freq_samples
    HA_point_size = (max_HA-min_HA)/sampling_H
    

    # create an empty RFI array which take the shape of the freq meshgrid
    RFI = np.zeros(freq.shape)
    point_size_label = np.zeros((freq.shape[0], freq.shape[1], 64))
    # print(freq.shape)
    
    # create an empty RFI array which take the shape of the freq meshgrid
    RFI = np.zeros(freq.shape)
    point_size_label = np.zeros((freq.shape[0], freq.shape[1], 64))
    # print(freq.shape)
    
    classification = classifications
    description = descriptions
    amp = amplitude



     # loop through the classifications
    for i in range(len(classification)):
        # print(classification[i])
        # loop through the amplitudes
        for j in range(len(amp)):
            # check if the classification is continuous
            if classification[i] == 'continuous':
                # get an array of the amplitude values with the same index as the frequency array
                amp_array = amp[j]*np.ones(freq.shape)
                # get a 2D array of the start and end frequencies of the current classification
                freq_range = rfi_data[rfi_data['Classification'] == classification[i]][['start_freq','end_freq']].values *10**-3 # convert to GHz otherwise it will be THz
                # get the RFI of the continuous classification by checking if the frequency is in the range of the current classification
                RFI += np.where(np.logical_and(freq >= freq_range[j][0], freq <= freq_range[j][1], RFI), amp_array, RFI)
                
                
    return RFI
```

To get a glimpse of the data, this is how the data looks like;
| Frequency | Classification | start_freq | end_freq | amplitude |
| --------- | -------------- | ---------- | -------- | --------- |
| 1000      | intermittent   | 1000       | 1000     | 0.299792  |
| 1030      | intermittent   | 1030       | 1030     | 0.291061  |
| 1025-1150 | intermittent   | 1025       | 1150     | 0.260689  |
| 1090      | intermittent   | 1090.0     | 1090.0   | 0.275039  |
| 1166-1186 | continuous     | 1166       | 1186     | 0.252776  |

What confuses me is that I am getting the data if I try to print them but keep getting an error when I call the function which reads;

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/r8/hbbztfpn4ns1pgl0687hmwp40000gp/T/ipykernel_66490/1561735211.py in <module>
----> 1 calculate_RFI(classifications, descriptions, amplitude)

/var/folders/r8/hbbztfpn4ns1pgl0687hmwp40000gp/T/ipykernel_66490/1341244216.py in calculate_RFI(classifications, descriptions, amplitude, freq_samples, min_freq, max_freq, min_HA, max_HA, sampling_H)
     59                 freq_range = rfi_data[rfi_data['Classification'] == classification[i]][['start_freq','end_freq']].values *10**-3 # convert to GHz otherwise it will be THz
     60                 # get the RFI of the continuous classification by checking if the frequency is in the range of the current classification
---> 61                 RFI += np.where(np.logical_and(freq >= freq_range[j][0], freq <= freq_range[j][1], RFI), amp_array, RFI)
     62 
     63 

IndexError: index 20 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 20
```

Comment: What confuses you about this error? Did you expect the index to be smaller than 20 or did you expect the array to be larger than 20?

Comment: to be exactly 20 since those are the amplitude values in the dataframe where the classification is `continuous`.

Comment: As the error mesage says, index 20 for an array with size 20 is out of bounds. For an array with size 20 the valid indices are 0 to 19.

Comment: yes , the values are chosen from the amplitude array and matched with those in the freq array. which I can't figure how to do it

Comment: the problem is freq_range, if you add a print statement after the assignment you will see the issue. freq_range is a subset of rfi_data (unless classifications is always "continuos") therefore there will by a j greater than max rows of freq_range that will cause the out of range error